# No kinect connected...waiting for devices to be connected

Tags: kinect, turtlebot, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use Ubuntu 12.04.02 LTS , and ROS fuerte.
but if I press 'roslaucnh openni_launch openni.launch', no device connected......
How can I solve this situation???

***UPDATE***

rostopic list result

```
turtlebot@turtlebot-AO756:~$ rostopic list 
/cmd_vel 
/diagnostics 
/diagnostics_agg 
/diagnostics_toplevel_state 
/imu/data 
/imu/raw 
/joint_states 
/laptop_charge 
/odom 
/robot_pose_ekf/odom 
/rosout 
/rosout_agg 
/tf 
/turtlebot/app_list 
/turtlebot/application/app_status 
/turtlebot_node/parameter_descriptions 
/turtlebot_node/parameter_updates 
/turtlebot_node/sensor_state 
turtlebot@turtlebot-AO756:~$
```

ros version is fuerte , ubuntu version is 12.04

and i robot create's kinect status light is red.

I don't know what is the problem.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67876/no-kinect-connected...waiting-for-devices-to-be-connected.../) by [FourTrees](https://answers.ros.org/users/5449/fourtrees/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2013-07-20

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @FourTrees,

This could be a classic error I have faced before because of the process XnSensorServer.

It would be more useful if you can also share with us the output for

> rostopic list

However, I can suggest you a possible solution (way around) which might just work. You need to basically restart the XnSensorServer Process. This can be done using the following two lines of command:

> killall XnSensorServer

> XnSensorServer

After performing this try to roslaunch the openni.launch file. Let us know if this works. Just to add to your information this happens when you launch openni topics multiple times as sometimes the XnSensorServer process is not properly cleared and shutdown.

Please note that if you have the process XnSensorServer linked to any other program or doing something else killing the process may not be a safe choice. It is advisable to kill/ Terminate any other processes using XnSensorServer before killing this process.

GoodLuck,

Regards,

Sivam

---

Originally posted by [SivamPillai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2018/sivampillai/) with karma: 612 on 2013-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Devasena Inupakutika](https://answers.ros.org/users/4122/devasena-inupakutika/) on 2013-07-20**:
In addition to above workaround, there is a possibility that your kinect is not powered although it might be connected to robot you are working on...but direct power supply should also be there... For this make sure yellow light glows on Kinect..

**Comment by [Devasena Inupakutika](https://answers.ros.org/users/4122/devasena-inupakutika/) on 2013-07-20**:
Also, in case above step has been followed, Please check if your robot is charged. Please do check the output of lsusb once and you can refer this too:
http://answers.ros.org/question/12107/kinect-no-devices-connected-on-openni_nodelaunch/

**Comment by [Athoesen](https://answers.ros.org/users/8296/athoesen/) on 2013-11-06**:
I have a follow-up question.  I can get my Linux 12.04 with ROSHydro system to run two kinects perfectly fine, but when I try to launch the 3rd it comes up with an error that says "Application XnSensorSever has closed unexpectedly".  These Kinects are all on different buses btw.  Any ideas?

**Comment by [Gloria@HK](https://answers.ros.org/users/14486/gloria@hk/) on 2014-06-19**:
Hydro, openni_launch, No kinect connected...waiting for devices to be connected...
Solution:
sudo apt-get remove libopenni-*
sudo apt-get install libopenni-*
download the openni_launch again.
And then it works!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is the best solution i could ever come up with.

Go to synaptic manager and reinstall all the openni packages.

[Avin2 GitHub snapshot of SensorKinect drivers](https://github.com/avin2/SensorKinect/zipball/unstable) - look in Bin folder
and use the package relevant to your OS to install the driver.

Then install NITE 1.5.2.21 driver present [here](http://www.mira-project.org/downloads/3rdparty/bin-linux/)

Now run openni_launch that run runs without any error and then run openni_tracker for skeleton tracking.

---

Originally posted by [gaussian](https://answers.ros.org/users/21014/gaussian/) with karma: 88 on 2015-01-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2